# Accessing class-level values of type parameters in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a trait and a case class implementing it. One of the features of the trait that the implementations override is a default value. I can't find a good way to access this default value from a class that is parametrized by a specific implementation of that trait.

This is minimal code, so it doesn't really demonstrate the motivation anymore, but it does demonstrate the error:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

trait Distance[T] {
  val Zero: T
  def +( that: T ): T
}

case class DoubleDistance( val v: Double ) extends Distance[DoubleDistance] {
  val Zero = DoubleDistance( 0.0 )
  def +( that: DoubleDistance ) = DoubleDistance( v + that.v )
}

object DistanceImplicits {
  implicit def DoubleToDistance( v: Double ) = new DoubleDistance( v )
}

class User[T<:Distance[T]] {
  val default: T = T.Zero // This line gives me a compilation error
}
```

The error I get is

```
not found: value T
```

When I needed to construct an `Array[T]` inside my `User` class I could get that to work by adding `implicit typetag:ClassTag[T]` to my arguments, but that doesn't seem to have any effect here.

Comment: Once it became clear that type classes was the concept I needed, I found [this article](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html) very useful in addition to the one Aaron linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, why this doesn't work: consider a different implementation of `Distance`.

```
case class DoubleDistance1(val v: Double) extends Distance[DoubleDistance1] {
  val Zero = this
  def +(that: DoubleDistance1) = ??? // doesn't matter
}
```

What would you expect `DoubleDistance1.Zero` to mean? You can make it work using a "type class":

```
trait DistanceOps[T] {
  val zero: T
  def add(d1: T, d2: T): T
}

// just to let you write distance1 + distance2
implicit class RichDistance[T](d: T)(implicit ops: DistanceOps[T]) {
  def +(other: T) = ops.add(d, other)
}

case class DoubleDistance(v: Double)

object DoubleDistance {
  implicit object DoubleDistanceOps extends DistanceOps[DoubleDistance] {
    val zero = DoubleDistance(0.0)
    def add(d1: DoubleDistance, d2: DoubleDistance) = DoubleDistance(d1.v + d2.v)
  }
}

// how to use
class User[T](implicit ops: DistanceOps[T]) {
  val default: T = ops.zero
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a classic use case for the [type class pattern](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/05/28/scala-type-classes-demystified/). Rather than associating an instance of the `Distance` trait with each *value* of interest, you associate one with each *type* of interest:

```
trait Distance[T] {
  val Zero: T
  def +( a: T, b: T ): T
}

implicit object DoubleDistance extends Distance[Double] {
  val Zero = 0.0
  def +( a: Double, b: Double ) = a + b
}

class User[T : Distance] {
  val default: T = implicitly[Distance[T]].Zero 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is that Zero supposed to come from? Are you looking to do something like this?

```
class User[T<:Distance[T]] {
  self:Distance[T] =>
  val default: T = Zero
}
```